# Google sitemap with tx_news

Tags: typo3-8.x, tx-news, xml-sitemap

I try to build a google sitemap with typo3 8.7.15, tx_news 6.3.0 and dd_googlesitemap  2.1.4
I chose /?eID=dd_googlesitemap&id=1&sitemap=txnews&singlePid=19&pidList=13&L=0 with singlePid (my site for the detail-page) and pidList with the url of the folder in which the news are stored. L=0 - I have no extra language so I tried without.
In both variants the google map is empty - anyone any idea? Here the complete URL: http://www.sbo-guetersloh.de/?eID=dd_googlesitemap&id=1&sitemap=txnews&singlePid=19&pidList=13&L=0

Answer (score 0):

Insert page root in id

http://www.sbo-guetersloh.de/?eID=dd_googlesitemap&id=1&sitemap=txnews&singlePid=19&pidList=13&L=0

Ex:
id=1212        - Site root page id
sitemap=txnews - type txnews (for plugin tx_news)
singlePid=19   - id for detail page
pidList=13     - data stored id